# DataTime with Slovenian Culture (sl-SI) has spaces

Tags: c#, datetime, culture

I've prepared a small WPF app:

View:

[image]

and the View-Model looks as following:

[image]

And now, for some reason there are spaces between the Day, Month and year for the Slovenian culture:

[image]

I mean that intead of getting 14.01.2019, I get 14. 01. 2019.

Comment: Whatever it is (see answers below), it most definitely isn't a C# bug, as that's a programming language.

Comment: @IanKemp: I don't think that's really the case - see my answer, which cites the Unicode CLDR. That's pretty much the canonical source of information here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Using archaic knowledge you gained developing NodaTime is cheating. :p But thanks for that, I had no idea the CLDR existed until now, next time I have a culture formatting-related question I know where to go!

Comment: Some related informations on this matter: [Why might my local machine be incorrectly formatting international dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53138834/7444103)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct behavior according to [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/). The easiest way of exploring the data is via the [GitHub repository of JSON format files](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full). The [generic dates file for "sl"](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates-full/blob/6227cc013572391189a63350cec2544f0e0b3624/main/sl/ca-generic.json#L310) (there's no specific sl-SI directory) contains this section:

```
"dateFormats": {
  "full": "EEEE, dd. MMMM y G",
  "long": "dd. MMMM y G",
  "medium": "d. MMM y G",
  "short": "d. MM. yy GGGGG"
}
```

So that looks like .NET is doing the right thing.

Comment: BTW, in case someone doesn't familiar with those formats, `G` is for "Era" and `E` is for day names. `EEEE` means wide day name like `Monday` and `GGGGG` means narrow description of "Era" like `A` (for `AD`). http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Answer (score 1):

According to wiki [Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

- **Slovenia** `d. mm. yyyy` or `dd. mmmm yyyy`

However ,i note the citation is actually a Microsoft page (the citation doesn't work atm)

So for it being a bug, i doubt it. As for being what most people there use (well it might depend who you ask)