# How character expansions does work under the hood?

Tags: unicode, encoding, cultureinfo, culture

I am reading the `CLR VIA C#` by Jeffrey Richter. And while explaining string comparison, he notes that:

> When the Compare method is not performing an ordinal comparison, it
>   performs ***character expansions***. A character expansion is when a
>   character is expanded to multiple characters regardless of culture.

```
String s1 = "Strasse";
String s2 = "Straße";
Boolean eq;

CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-­DE");
eq = String.Compare(s1, s2, true, ci) == 0; // returns true
```

For the above case, he notes:

> ...the German Eszet character ‘ß’ is always expanded to
>   ‘ss. So in the code example, the call to Compare will always
>   return 0 regardless of which culture I actually pass in to it.

I want to know from which source, the runtime takes that `ß` is equal to `ss` or how it calculates it?

Comment: The [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs,1356715f78447ed6,references) leads to unmanaged code, `COMNlsInfo::InternalCompareString` so it's a dead end

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf)

Comment: Read the first line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53138834/7444103). Or maybe follow the link.

Comment: [A DIN standard?](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/tr10-43.html#Special_Cases)